# A question about a long-shunt compound DC generator

Tags: dc, generator, homework

I am an engineering student and I encountered a tricky question while doing my assignment.

The question is as follows:

> A long-shunt compound DC generator rated at 20 kW and 200 V has a total
> armature circuit resistance of 0.3 ohms and a shunt field resistance of 50 ohms.
>
> (a) Drawing an equivalent circuit for the generator with explanations for
> each parameter in the circuit.
>
> (b) Estimate the load, field and armature currents at full load.
>
> (c) Estimate the generated voltage at full load at rated terminal voltage.
>
> (d) Explain the difference between the terminal voltage and internal
> generated voltage.

By now I already finished the part (a) and (b) of the question. The load, field and armature currents should be 100A, 4A and 104A if I recall correctly. But I get stuck while attempting part (c) of the question.

So as the question stated, we are required to find out the generated voltage at full load at rated terminal voltage of the dc generator. I tried to do so but I can't since I failed to find out the series field resistance of the generator, which I believe is needed to solve the part. So is the series field resistance necessary in solving this part? Or I am missing some governing equations? Could anyone provide me with some assistance?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No series field.  Or you couldn't do a or b.

Comment: I would state my assumption that as the series field winding is part of the armature circuit, it is included in the "total armature circuit resistance". Otherwise why call that resistance the "total"?

Comment: You should post the drawing that you made for (A). For (A), how did you explain total armature circuit resistance? Did you explain "generated voltage"?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I would contact my professor to see if the total armature circuit resistance refers to the summation of resistance of the armature and series field winding as you guys suggested. Really appropriate your help!